# Laravel Yajra datatable global Search filter

Tags: laravel, filter, datatable, yajra-datatable

I have this technical difficulty when want to use laravel yajra datatable to write custom global search query

Reference
https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/filter-column

when I do some search by passing in calendar date and searchbox value, I'm stuck at correct way to write it

Only the main `->filter  got triggered`

The `->filterColumn skipped through`.... not sure why...

In sql vanila, it is

```
where firstname like %search% OR
lastname like %search% OR
fullname like %search% OR
email like %search% OR
sponsorby like %search% OR
createddate like %date%
```

Here is my code for reference. filterCustom is not triggered...

```
if ($request->ajax()) {

    $users = \DB::select('
    SELECT id, usercode as membercode, concat(firstname, " ", lastname) as fullname, email, created_at as createddate, (select concat(firstname, " ", lastname) from users where id= m.parentid) sponsorby
    FROM users m 
    ORDER BY m.created_at ASC');
```

Update: I realize yajra doesn't support DB::select with full raw sql, however it support DB::table
So I change my sql to below,

```
        $users = \DB::table('users')
            ->select('id', 'usercode as membercode', \DB::raw('concat(firstname, " ", lastname) as fullname'), 'email', 'created_at as createddate', \DB::raw('(select concat(firstname, " ", lastname) from users as b where b.id= users.parentid) as sponsorby'));
  //end

     return Datatables::of($users)

             ->addColumn('membercode', function($row){
                $content= $row->membercode;
               return $content;
            })

            ->addColumn('fullname', function($row){
                $content= $row->fullname;
               return $content;
            })
            
            ->addColumn('email', function($row){
                $content= $row->email;
               return $content;
            })        

            //etc




                ->filter(function ($sql) use ($request) {
                     
                     $search = $request->search;

                     if (!empty($search)) 
                     {
                                                         
                        $sql->Where('email', 'LIKE', "%$search%");                           
                     }

                 })

                ->filterColumn('fullname', function($query, $request) {
                    $search = $request->search;
                    $sql = 'concat(firstname, " ", lastname)  like ?';
                    $query->whereRaw($sql, ["%{$search}%"]);
                })

                ->filterColumn('membercode', function($query, $request) {
                    $search = $request->search;
                    $sql = 'usercode as membercode  like ?';
                    $query->whereRaw($sql, ["%{$search}%"]);
                })

                ->filterColumn('createddate', function($query, $request) {
                    $search = $request->date;
                    $sql = 'created_at as createddate  like ?';
                    $query->whereRaw($sql, ["%{$search}%"]);
                })

                 ->filterColumn('sponsorby', function($query, $request) {
                    $search = $request->search;
                    $sql = '(select concat(firstname, " ", lastname) from users as b where b.id= users.parentid)   like ?';
                    $query->whereRaw($sql, ["%{$search}%"]);
                })

             ->make(true);
 }
```